# Outdoor camera housing angled parallel to wall

Tags: security

Am in need of an outdoor camera housing that would fit under an awning, against a house wall, but follow the curves of those two surfaces (as in a right angled back), which would also have the clear panel that the camera could see out of facing down the wall, perhaps a slightly angle out from it.

What have others done to provide an indoor camera protection from the elements in this way before?

Comment: Can you provide a picture, or two?  That helps a lot with these kinds of issues.

Comment: You can surely get, or even fabricate, a weather-tight box. But why? Why not just install an outdoor-rated camera? Your question seems very broad. Without knowing what you've tried already, and what your specific constraints are, it's impossible to know what the right answer is.

Comment: @SteveSh - Will capture some pictures this weekend, when I can get natural light on the install location.

Comment: @PeterDuniho - Because I already have a suitable camera to use. I have not tried anything (was hoping that there was a commercially available solution, but have searched the likes of Amazon without luck). Constraint is only that it is waterproof; has space inside for one of those indoor cameras that are in black housing, has a U mounting on it, that are so prevalent a shape and size on Amazon/the like that I swear it is a industry standard; and is of the shape and has a 'window' on the side mentioned in the question. Any other information needed?

Comment: _"I already have a suitable camera to use"_ -- judging from your question, I'd say that actually, you don't. But, if you have a specific camera you intend to put in the box, your question should include details about that exact camera.

Comment: @PeterDuniho - A camera is chosen based on field of view, and resolution, not on what box it will fit into. Choosing a crappy camera just because it will fit in a box does not meet the purpose of a camera, that is installed to capture footage at a certain distance, a certain scope, and a certain level of detail. Every not suitable mouting location housing I have looked at has been big enough for my camera, but if it is essential to you to have dimensions to work of, do so off - https://www.amazon.com/CrazyFire-Panasonic-2-8-12mm-Digital-Security/dp/B00L454KHY

Comment: You could choose a non-crappy outdoor-rated camera. But whatever. You want to use a different definition of "suitable" than what I think is correct, that's your prerogative. You're the one here looking for help with this so-called "suitable" camera. :p

Comment: @PeterDuniho - My questions asks for a camera housing.... Not an outdoor camera that duplicates what I already have, and doesn't provide much protection against vandalism. Instead of debating me, you could just provide something that suits the request (matching the provided level of detail, however inspecific you feel it will be), or let someone else do so.

Comment: _"...an outdoor camera that duplicates what I already have, and doesn't provide much protection against vandalism"_ -- your question asks about the elements, not vandalism. So, a) an outdoor camera wouldn't duplicate what you already have (since by your statement, the camera in question needs protection from the elements), and b) since you never asked about vandalism, what makes you think you'd get an answer addressing that aspect? _"you could just provide something that suits the request"_ -- your request lacks enough detail for a good answer to be provided.

Comment: @PeterDuniho - Seeing as any housing provides an element of valdalism protection vs. a outdoor camera that has only seals on it's single layer housing to prevent moisture entering, I didn't see the need to state this. If I was looking for a vandal-proof camera housing, I would have stated this. I already have a camera. Buying an outdoor camera gives me 2 cameras, ergo duplication?! Ever thought that I am not looking for the most 100% perfect answer?

Comment: @PeterDuniho - Any answer that is a camera housing that looks different to ALL I have seen on Amazon may provide terminology I am not familiar with that will lead me on the right track, introduce me to a brand with other design options that may suit, or may even be exactly what I am looking for. Besides, if the request is too specific, I am limiting my options (and the possibility of anyone answering).